# How to change device orientation on androidmanifest.xml based on device using

Tags: android, react-native

How to change device orientation on androidmanifest.xml based on device I'm using. Sample if i use tablet.. it would be landscape, and when i use an android phone it would be portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React-Native you can use [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) to lock the orientation of the device. Then, you can use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info) to get informations on the device and lock the orientation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So here in your case you cant do via android manifest. you need to dynamically change orientation based on device.

So you have to build a native module. expose it to react native[RN-native modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

and use it based on your type of device. Its a very easy native module like you have to setOrientation

```
@ReactMethod
public void setOrientation(String type) {
  if(type == 'landscape'){
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
  if(type == 'portrait'){
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

}
```

so basically this method will be exposed to your react native side. you need to detect the type of device.

Hope it helps. feel free for any doubts.